# I am getting an error when using FormatMessage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The error I get is as follows:

> Additional information: Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of formatmessage function

This is the structure I am using:

```
FORMATMESSAGE('https://static.arkadas.com.tr/ProductImages/Orginal/%s_Default.jpg', p.ItemStockCode) as [İmage Link]
```

How can I fix this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014, it works without any error, but when I write this query in a class in SQL query, I get an error. @NealBurns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `FORMATMESSAGE()` only accepts a string for the first argument since SQL Server 2016. Prior to SQL Server 2016, `FORMATMESSAGE()` expects the first argument to be a number, which identifies a message in sys.messages.

You can do this:

```
'https://static.arkadas.com.tr/ProductImages/Orginal/' + p.ItemStockCode + '_Default.jpg'
```

Comment: And you add to `sys.messages` via [`sp_addmessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I understand, thank you very much. Well, can I ask you something, is there a column like this that you can suggest otherwise? @NealBurns